# 2 'The's with 2 consecutive nouns joined with a conjunction: "X and Y", "the X and Y", or "the X and the Y"?

Tags: articles, ellipsis, parallelism

"Please write the transliteration and translation for the following words."

Is the sentence above grammatically correct?  Do I need to put the other 'the' before 'translation' as well, or is it possible to not use 'the' at all in this sentence?  Please accept my gratitude in advance for your kind assistance.

Answer (score 4):

I take this sentence as grammatical (but an extra "the" could definitely be added). This is because the writer is treating "transliteration and translation" as two things so closely related that they are treated as **one group**.

In a similar sense, we usually say "Can you pass the salt and pepper?" as oppose to "Can you pass the salt and the pepper?"